# ntp + ntp loose synchronize each time in 5:00 morning

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, time, date, ntp

we have a very strange behavior

we have 12 Linux redhat machines - redhat 7.x

two of these VM servers are loosing the time synchronize each day at 5:00 in the morning

after we restart the chronyd , then sync return to normal

but what could be the reason for this strange behavior ?

```
systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-07-12 20:49:43 UTC; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 971 (chronyd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
           └─971 /usr/sbin/chronyd
```

the servers:

```
dmidecode | grep -i vm
        Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
        Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
        Serial Number: VMware-42 24 19 ee 87 95 0b a8-16 da b6 ce d3 4e ff 6a
        Description: VMware SVGA II
        String 1: [MS_VM_CERT/SHA1/27d66596a61c48dd3dc7216fd715126e33f59ae7]
```

Comment: Do you mean that the servers _are_ VMs or do you mean that they _host_ VMs?

Comment: Are there any suspicious journal messages immediately before the time sync is lost?

Comment: the servers are VMs ( see the update of the question )

Comment: we not see  journal messages